# Sharing my Laptops internet connection via wifi by creating a hotspot

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a HP Compaq NX7400 netbook.

It has a Windows XP SP 2 OS. You have probably heard about people turning their laptops into Wi-Fi hotspots. I have a Tata Photon+ dongle which I use as internet on my NX7400. I also have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 620 with Android 3.2 on which I want to use the internet of my Compaq using Wi-Fi creators.

I already tried Connectify but it has a minimum requirement of Windows XP SP3 while mine is SP2.

How can I make my laptop a Wi-Fi hotspot and use the internet on my tablet? Or do I have hardware issues?

Comment: Upgrade to XP SP3. With the number of known security vulnerabilities in SP2, it's not a wise idea to directly expose it to the internet, nor allow other computers to connect through it.

Answer (score 1):

Best software is ofcourse Windows XP SP3 :)

That said, there is a google trick to find similar softwares, for instance, to find connectify alternatives, type `connectify vs` in the search bar to get loads of suggestions. Using that trick I have found the following alternatives : [Virtual router](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/12/28/4-Reasons-Why-Virtual-Router-is-Superior-to-Connectify.aspx), [mHotspot](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/Access-point-mHotspot-hotspot-WPA2-Wi-Fi-Range-Extensibility,news-12511.html) and [others](http://alternativeto.net/software/connectify/)